# How to maintain a centralized Object across the application

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am developing an application where I need to create an object and multiple classes have to access and modify that object. How to see the recent changes made by the other class object and how to access the object centrally through all the classes with out passing that object as a parameter across all the classes?

I am creating an Apache POI document where I am adding multiple tables, multiple headers/footers and paragraphs. I want only a single `XWPFDocument` object present in my application.

Is there any design pattern we can achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for a global object , that's bad !

Comment: Then what will be the best approach? suggest me @TheNewIdiot

Comment: @TheNewIdiot having a global object is not bad because probably you only need a single instance of it through the application, the problem is how you plan to maintain this single instance.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks you understood the requirment

Comment: Based on the description of your real problem, looks like you need a single `XWPFDocument` instance when creating the document. This could be done with builder design pattern.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes Only one instance of XWPFDocument should present across the application. SO that I can append text to it in another class. For example in a class I added a tableA to the document and in other class If i add tableB that must use the existing doc instance and it adds tableB which comes after tableA in the document.

Comment: The fact that you use different classes to add data in it doesn't mean you need a single instance through the whole application. What kind of application are you developing: desktop, mobile or web?

Comment: It's a static plugin(OSGi). Java application. I have abstract methods, My document must be referenced in the extended classes. That's the real case here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34208/discussion-between-maheshvarma-and-luiggi-mendoza)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the [singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) would *work* - but isn't terribly clean; you end up with global static state which is hard to keep track of and hard to test. It's often considered an anti-pattern these days. There are a *very* few cases where it still makes sense, but I try to avoid it.

A better approach would be to use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection): make each class which needs one of these objects declare a constructor parameter of that type (or possibly have a settable property). Each class shouldn't care too much about how shared or otherwise the object is (beyond being aware that it *can* be shared). Then it's up to the code which initializes the application to decide which objects should be shared.

There are various dependency injection frameworks available for Java, including [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) and [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework). The idea of these frameworks is to automatically wire up all the dependencies in your application, given appropriate configuration.

Comment: +1, but stateful singleton -> no! , if its a single node webapp I would store it in servlet context

Comment: @JigarJoshi: The OP hadn't included that context when I wrote the answer. I'll edit appropriately. (I'm not sure I'd use the servlet context either though...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Only one instance of XWPFDocument should present across the application. SO that I can append text to it in another class. For example in a class I added a tableA to the document and in other class If i add tableB that must use the existing doc instance and it adds tableB which comes after tableA in the document.

Comment: @MaheshVarma: Yes, so you provide a reference to the same document to the constructors for both classes.

Comment: here is a nice tutorial on dependency injection http://lowcoupling.com/post/47844360084/a-survey-on-dependency-injection . The main idea is that to avoid singletons you use singletons (or class with static methods) to inject objects :))

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for fast reply. I have abstract methods, My document must be referenced in the extended classes. That's the real case here.

Comment: @JonSkeet if you explain your statement "you end up with global static state which is hard to keep track of and hard to test", it would be helpful. i always hear that singleton are hard to test, but i dont know why? why we cant test it like any other object. I am sure there is some reason behind it, but somehow i am missing it

Comment: @MaheshVarma: I don't see how that's relevant at all. Something must be creating instances of those subclasses - so pass the document into the constructor (or have it as a parameter for the abstract methods).

Comment: @MSach: Once the singleton has been created, how do you go back to a state where it *isn't* created, so that you can test different scenarios? There are options such as adding a "resetForTest" method, but test-specific methods in production code are a warning sign in themselves.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, But My requirement is not to pass as a reference

Comment: @MaheshVarma I don't think that's not your requirement, instead an odd constraint for your design. Are you really sure about this?

Comment: @Jon Skeet. Got you. But we can have resetForTest method in each test class and execute it before execution of each test case method.

Comment: @MSach: No, you'd need to put it in the *singleton* type itself, not in the test code. It's really ugly.

Comment: @MaheshVarma: Passing references *is* how you share objects in Java. If you're going to state such an odd (and impossible) requirement, you should do so up-front in the question from the very start, and give *much* more clarity about what you mean.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, got it

Answer (score 3):

There is [Singleton Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html) for this, it creates a single instance for the application and is shared without passing around.

But it not not the best of options.

> Why is it a bad option?

- It is not good for testability of code
- Not extensible in design

Better than Singleton Pattern is an application wide single instance

Create a single object for the application and share it using some context object. More on this is explained by [Misko in his guide to testable code](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/)

> single instance and not Singleton Pattern

It stands for an application wide single instance, which  **DOES NOT** inforce its singletonness through a static instance field.

> Why are Singletons hard to test?

- Static access prevents collaborating with a subclass or wrapped version of another class. By hard-coding the dependency, we lose the power and flexibility of polymorphism.
  -Every test using global state needs it to start in an expected state, or the test will fail. But another object might have mutated that global state in a previous test.
- Global state often prevents tests from being able to run in parallel, which forces test suites to run slower.
- If you add a new test (which doesn’t clean up global state) and it runs in the middle of the suite, another test may fail that runs after it.
- Singletons enforcing their own “Singletonness” end up cheating.
  You’ll often see mutator methods such as `reset()` or `setForTest(…)` on so-called singletons, because you’ll need to change the instance during tests. If you forget to reset the Singleton after a test, a later use will use the stale underlying instance and may fail in a way that’s difficult to debug.

Comment: I've never heard of "singleton with a small s" - creating a single instance of an object isn't the same as making it a singleton. A singleton *prevents* multiple instances from being created. This terminology can only lead to confusion, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have read it in Misko's blog that I have link to in my answer. IMO it is a better option compared to Singleton pattern. I would add the meaning with the answer too.

Comment: The article you referred to explicitly says that "Adding or using singletons" is a warning sign - so it's not even consistent *within the same page*. Surely that's an indication that this subtle differentation is worth avoiding.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree, but I took some positives of the post and I avoid using Singleton for sake of testability.

Comment: If you agree that it's terminology to avoid, why are you propagating it in your post? Why not just talk about a single instance which is created within application startup, and not try to call it a "singleton with a small s"?

Comment: I will just remove that terminology and call it single instance.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have removed the terminology. Thanks for pointing it out.